# Python: Is it possible to Authenticate through Gmail API without opening browser

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, google-oauth, gmail-api

In Step 3 of [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) instruction they show how to use it and access data.

But after running program it opens up the browser and then it ask us to authenticate and shows allow button to give access to your data.

Now my question is that, is it possible to Authenticate any account without really opening any browser. Like set up username and password and then it will automatically do all the authentication stuff and get the data from there without really opening browser.

Or I will have to use scraping techniques like BeautifulSoup and then open up that link and then click on that button.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part where it is opening the browser window is Oauth2.   You are prompting a user to grant you access to their private Gmail data.   There used to be a way of doing this with login and password it was called client login.  In 2015 Google shut down the option for client login.

If you wish to access a users gmail account using login and password you can still go though the IMAP/Smtp servers.  that is the only way to do it without popping up that window.

Note: if you have a gsuit account you can use domain wide delegation on a service account as well.